# Django Models entering data

Tags: django

Im quite lost in this models, i want to Enter data in CourseScore. Course score will point to one student, and one course which the student registered. 
I want to do automatic calculation at the time of data entry.

```
    from django.db import models
    from student.models import Student
    # Create your models here.
    class Course(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        finternalmark=models.IntegerField(default=40)
        fexternalmark = models.IntegerField(default=100)
        fullmark = models.IntegerField()

        def CalculateFullMark(self):
            self.fullmark = self.finternalmark + self.fexternalmark


        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.name}-{self.fintegermark}-{self.fexternalmark}'

    class CourseRegistration(models.Model):
        student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.student}'

    class CourseScore(models.Model):
        #entering marks for one course
        CourseRegn = models.OneToOneField(CourseRegistration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        internalmark = models.IntegerField()
        externalmark = models.IntegerField()
        marks = models.IntegerField()

        def CalculateMarks(self):
            self.marks = self.internalmark + self.externalmark



    class SemesterResult(models.Model):

        student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        courses=  models.ForeignKey(CourseScore,on_delete=models.CASCADE) # course in which the student is registered and marks are entered
        totalmarks=models.IntegerField()
        grandtotal = models.IntegerField()

        def CalculateTotalMarks(self):
            pass
            #calculate totalmarks = sum of marks scored in courses that the students opted

        def CalculateGrandTotal(self):
            pass
            #calculate grandtotal = sum of all fullmarks of the course that the student opted
```

Comment: Did you read this section of Django doc [Creating Model objects- Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the attributes you want to automatically calculate property methods using the @property decorator instead of calculating it in your model function :

```
    @property
    def marks(self):
        return self.internalmark + self.externalmark
```